# how can I modify this javascript code for WebSocket functionality

Tags: javascript

I used following code without error:

```
"use strict";
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://testnet.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=trade:XBTUSD"); 
ws.onmessage = function(e) {document.getElementById("outtext").value = e.data};
```

but when I substitute "trade" with "position" gives an error, this is for "position" related to every user account which needs authentication, that needs API Key and API Secret for each user.

My question is how do I do this modification to work in website **for public users**.

thanks.

**Edit:**
I can't add a comment probably due to my browser problem, so with inserting the code piece into a html file we get:

*{"status":401,"error":"User requested an account-locked subscription but no authorization was provided.","meta":{"notes":"Account-locked tables include the following: account,affiliate,execution,margin,order,position,privateNotifications,transact,wallet"},"request":{"op":"subscribe","args":"position:XBTUSD"}}*

**Edit2:** here is the html sample:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<textarea id="outtext" style="position:absolute;left:300px;top:1px;width:700px;height:600px;z-index:0;" rows="13" cols="40"></textarea>
<script>
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://testnet.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=trade:XBTUSD"); 
ws.onmessage = function(e) {document.getElementById("outtext").value = e.data}; 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please post the error message?

Comment: How are you getting the key/secret? Sounds like you need to dynamically append them to the URL